# Signaling Pathway Impact Analysis (SPIA) package for R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, analysis

Can someone tell me how to analyse data from a .xls file to perform a SPIA analysis? How do I have to load the data?

Comment: Do you mean and XLS file? as in Excel?

Comment: Yes, I need to import a file but using "read.table" is retrieving me a lot of NA spaces

Comment: Save xls files as CSV, then us `read.csv`.

Comment: Also note, Excel likes to convert some [gene names into dates](http://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-5-80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the xlsx package:

```
require(xlsx)
read.xlsx("myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
```

you have to tell which of your sheets you need to read.